# How to select polygons associated with (not necessarily containing) corresponding points?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I have a list of polygons, each associated with the x/y coordinates of a point. These points may not intersect the polygons. How can I select the polygons that do contain the corresponding point? I only have a ArcView license.

Comment: Is it possible that a point might be inside a polygon that it DOES NOT correspond to?

Comment: Is there a field on both point and polygon feature classes that contains an identifier to link the two?  If so, perhaps start by trying to add a Join in ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably lots of ways to do this.  Try a spatial join of points to polygons (keep only matching), then select by attributes only those polygons that match their joined points.  Or could you have more than one point in a polygon?